# laravel 5.5 login via google gives Client error

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I was trying to add the google login to my laravel project. but it gives a Client error. Given below is the error i got. I successfully installed the socialite as well.

```
 Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Project 983930379932 is not found (truncated...)
```

Comment: First Open your Google Console Account from Here : console.developers.google.com  

Select your project.
After this you have to click on google+ API detail page.
Now we can enable API.

Answer (score 16):

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis and enable Google+ api.

Took me 3 hours to find out that Google Cloud does not automatically enable the api for you when you create OAuth service.

Comment: You save my day

Answer (score 2):

Remember you have to register your google app within googles service as well. That error if I remember correctly is simply telling you that you aren't allowed to use google services.

I am not super sure if this steps are up to date, but it shouldn't be that different: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-google-oauth-authentication-using-socialite-packageexample.html

Answer (score 0):

First Open your Google Console Account from Here : console.developers.google.com

Select your project.
After this you have to click on google+ API detail page.
Now we can enable API.